# Does jQuery have a generic callback to avoid breaking chains?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sometimes I find myself quite happily chaining my way through a set of jQuery functions until I hit a condition.

Then I have to break my chain up into separate chunks, apply variables to each one and rethink the process

Consider the following snippet:

```js
var $options = $('#options');

$options.on('click', '.addoption', function () {
     $(this)
      .parent()
      .clone()
      .find('input')
      .val('')
      .parent()
      .appendTo($options)
      .find('label')
      .html('');
     $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="options">
            <div>
                <label class="label">options</label>
                <input name="option[]"/> 
                <button class="addoption" >+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Suppose I wanted to add a class to the input depending on a certain condition.

I could do something like:

```
...
 .find('input')
 .val('')
 .addClass(myCondition?'myClass':'')
 .parent()
...
```

But this would involve an unnecessary call to `.addClass()`  if `myCondition` was false, but moreover using a ternary operator wouldn't be practical in all situations.

What would be more convenient is something like:

```
...
 .find('input')
 .val('')
 .call(function(jQueryObject){
    if(myCondition){
        jQueryObject.addClass('myClass')
      }
  })
 .parent()
...
```

Where `call` is a method that runs a callback which receives the jQuery object itself as a parameter and then returns the jQuery object.

This would allow operations to be carried out on the object depending on conditions and then continue on with the unbroken chain.

I've read the documentation carefully but did not find any methods that look like they might do this.

This is something I might be able to implement myself by extending the jQuery object but I didn't wan to set about reinventing the wheel if such functionality already exists

Comment: `.each` does what you want (it works fine on a single item)

Comment: "But this would involve an unnecessary call to .addClass()...", ironically your pseudo code calls two functions. You are calling many methods. Adding another method to the list doesn't make a noticeable difference.

Comment: Personally I think breaking this up is better for readability anyway. While creating long chains *feels good*, they are harder to read especially when you come back later doing maintenance

Answer (score 2):

There is no such method. The jQuery way of testing a condition is using the `filter` method which as the name suggests, filters the collection. Since a jQuery object is a collection of elements, the method is useful for checking properties of each individual element and not for a general criterion. After filtering and calling the desired methods you can get the pre-filter collection using the `.end()` method.

```
$object
  .filter(function() {
     return true || false;
  })
  .addClass()
  .end()
  ...
```

If you want to test a condition and keep the jQuery object, you can cache it and use an `if` statement.

```
var $object = ...
              .find('input')
              .val('');

if ( condition ) {
   $object.addClass('class');
}
```

However, if you prefer to use a method instead of caching the object and using an `if` statement, you can define a method that works like the `filter` method but it filters the collection itself and not the collection's elements.

```
/**
  This method uses the jQuery `slice` method for slicing the collection.
  If the passed condition is a truhy value it returns the same collection,
  otherwise it returns the same collection without the elements. Using the
  `slice` is necessary for getting the pre-filter collection using the `end` method.
  @param {Boolean} condition
  @return {Object} the same jQuery object 
**/
$.fn.filterAll = function(condition) {
    return condition ? this.slice(0) : this.slice(0, 0);
};

$object
  .filterAll(condition)
  .addClass('foo')
  .end()
  ...
```

In this case, you could also use the `addClass` callback function. The callback function is executed once for each element in the collection. When `null` is returned, jQuery doesn't modify the element's `className` property.

```
...
 .find('input')
 .val('')
 .addClass(function() {
    // `this` keyword here refers to each element in the collection
    return condition ? 'class' : null;
  })
 .parent()
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .each function and pass a callback into it to do what you need.

```
...
.find('input')
.val('')
.each(function(jQueryObject){
if(myCondition){
  jQueryObject.addClass('myClass')
}
...
```

Comment: `jQueryObject` would be `index` of element within collect at `.each(index, element)`

Comment: You're right. I always forget that .each is (index, value, array), because I usually use JavaScript's built in .forEach which is (value, index array). Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing [`.toggleClass( className, state )`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass-className-state) , where `state` would be condition , `Boolean`

alternatively

```
$.fn.doStuff = function(condition, method, args, that) {
  if (condition) this[method](args);
  return that || this
}
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit See updated post . Included `.toggleClass()`  at post for example described at OP

Comment: You're still not actually reading the question. _"This is something I might be able to implement myself by extending the jQuery object but I didn't wan[t] to set about reinventing the wheel if such functionality already exists"_ The OP already knows how to do this, and is asking whether jQuery has an equivalent built-in. You should really _read the question_ before moving to answer it!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Could use  `.on()` , `trigger()` with custom event , namespace defined , though simplest would be to compose method, etc. to suit requirement - if _"The OP already knows how to do this"_  - rather than piece together jQuery methods that may not return actual expect result . Not necessarily _"reinventing the wheel"_ if read jQuery documentations and such method not found ?, but creating method that does specific task . Here , ternary option would be simplest

Comment: I don't understand your comment, sorry. Looks like maybe there are some words missing?

Comment: Your original `doStuff` is a good method. The second parameter can also be an object. Then we can iterate through the object's properties and execute the corresponding jQuery methods. This way we can avoid chaining the `doStuff` methods for executing several jQuery methods.

Comment: @Vohuman Perhaps several means of achieving requirement with existing jQuery methods ; `.end()` , `.addBack()` helpful to change `this` , or collection , maintain chainability at next method . Solution appear to depend on how flexible existing methods should be , or are versus specific details of expected results to be returned from method , if `context` changes within method ? Difficult to determine where to stop - if example case at OP is change `class` of element ?

Comment: I believe the main point of the question is performance + maintainability.  I had suggested using an object according to those criteria.